# Why Audio elements can't be assigned onended() callbacks directly

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, event-handling

This doesn't work as expected (at least in Chrome):

```
var a = new Audio();
a.src = "something.mp3";
a.onended = function() { console.log("ended"); }
```

This does:

```
var a = new Audio();
a.src = "something.mp3";
a.addEventListener('ended', function() { console.log("ended"); });
```

Is there any documentation to indicate why this is the case?

All other tags still seem to properly support "direct" event assignments. Why doesn't the audio tag/object? ... Is it a bug?

Comment: Works fine for me in the current canary build (33.0.1712.2), so I guess it's just a bug.